# Playing audio files in web page?

Tags: java, audio-streaming

I trying to write web application that recieves audio files from database and play them.Do you know any open source flash audio player for that?And i am also thinking implementing in java do you suggest java or another programming language for that?

Comment: Try asking one thing at a time, you will probably get a better response.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to be facetious but did you even *try* a Google search?

First result: http://musicplayer.sourceforge.net/

In the not-too-distant future you'll be able to use the HTML `<audio>` element to play files, too. Firefox 3.5 and Chrome already support it.

Comment: of course i googled it but players i found was not satisfy my needs.I asked for different opinions.By the way this is good one http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/ in case someone else needs.